# Reading malformed XML with Nokogiri: Unescaped Ampersands in URL field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to read a XML  file from a third party with Nokogiri in my rails project.
One of the nodes I have ot parse contains an URL with unescaped ampersands (like `foo.com/index.html?page=1&query=bar`)

I understand that this is considered malformed XML, and Nokogiri just tries to parse it anyway, resulting in `foo.com/index.html?page=1=bar`.

How can I obtain the full URL? Can I tweak Nokogiri? Would you do a search&replace-prerun or what would be the best practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tidy up malformed xml in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072738/how-to-tidy-up-malformed-xml-in-ruby)

Comment: I came up with just doing a manual cleaning here, as long as it is just this one malformed-ness, so what I do is `f = f.gsub('&','&amp;')` before I hand it over to `Nokogiri::XML` and do a `gsub('&amp;', '&')` on parsing the link... Of course if it turns out that the XML  is generally bad formed it would be too much to continue doing everything by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue parsing SVGs with image links containing ampersands.

Parsing SVGs as HTML seems to correctly handle the links, escaping &.

```
fixed_svg = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(raw_svg).to_html
# proceed with XML parsing
svg = Nokogiri::XML(fixed_svg)
```